# Where can I find the security options in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms

I'm trying to change server authentication mode, but all the [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16) that I'm finding about it points at a menu that does not appear for me.

Steps tried:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.

Yes, no problem at all.

2. On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.

There is no Security page visible to me. There's a bunch of different pages, but Security is not one of them. So where do I go?

Comment: What type of server are you actually using? On premises SQL Server? Azure SQL Edge? Azure SQL Database? Synapse? Something else?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Id hazard a guess that you don't have the permissions to change the authentication method then.

Comment: I basically just created the server with default settings, and did not create any other accounts. If I don't have permission than who does?